# How can I access variable from a callback method on Android

Tags: android, callback, android-mapview

I have a class named MapViewManager, in it I have a method called navigate like below:

```
public class MapViewManager{
    ...
    public void navigate(double startX, double startY, double toX, double toY, long floorId, boolean flag) {
        final FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("navigate");
        mapView.setLayerOffset(featureLayer);
        mapView.addLayer(featureLayer);

        final NavigateManager navigateManager = new NavigateManager();
        if (flag) {
            navigateManager.navigation(startX, startY, floorId, toX, toY, floorId);
        }else{
            navigateManager.clear();
        }

        navigateManager.setOnNavigateComplete(new NavigateManager.OnNavigateComplete() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigateComplete(NavigateManager.NavigateState navigateState,
                                       FeatureCollection featureCollection) {
                featureLayer.clearFeatures();
                featureLayer.addFeatures(featureCollection);

                for (int i=0;i<featureCollection.getSize();i++){
                    Feature feature = featureCollection.getFeature(i);
                    Coordinate coordinate = feature.getCentroid();
                    double x = coordinate.getX();
                    double y = coordinate.getY();   
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to access the variable named coordinate in onNavigateComplete callback method from outside so that other classes can use the coordinate variable to do something. How can I make it?

Comment: Declare `Coordinate coordinate` outside and best is do `coordinate` related code inside `onNavigateComplete`

Comment: I need all coordinate variables so that I declared an array list outside and inside I add every coordinate into that array list. But the array list size is always 0. How should I do to save all coordinate variables into a array list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more parameter to navigate method.

```
public class MapViewManager{
    ...
    public void navigate(double startX, double startY, double toX, double toY, long floorId, boolean flag, NavigateManager.OnNavigateComplete navigation) {
        final FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("navigate");
        mapView.setLayerOffset(featureLayer);
        mapView.addLayer(featureLayer);

        final NavigateManager navigateManager = new NavigateManager();
        if (flag) {
            navigateManager.navigation(startX, startY, floorId, toX, toY, floorId);
        }else{
            navigateManager.clear();
        }

        navigateManager.setOnNavigateComplete(navigation);
    }
}
```

Call method from other Class :

```
new MapViewManager().navigate(other paramter values, new NavigateManager.OnNavigateComplete() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigateComplete(NavigateManager.NavigateState navigateState,
                                       FeatureCollection featureCollection) {
                featureLayer.clearFeatures();
                featureLayer.addFeatures(featureCollection);

                for (int i=0;i<featureCollection.getSize();i++){
                    Feature feature = featureCollection.getFeature(i);
                    Coordinate coordinate = feature.getCentroid();
                    navigationPoints.add(coordinate);
                    double x = coordinate.getX();
                    double y = coordinate.getY();   
                }
            }
        });
```

Now you can access any object anywhere.

Comment: About the navigation parameter, what's type of it?

Comment: What I have done is, like if you call the navigate method from your activity and need to get the info on onNavigateComplete in Activity, then in method's paramters, I passed the listener instead of declaring that in MapViewManager Class.

Comment: Actually I didn't read the whole snippet because I didn't move it to the left. Now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it public by doing this:

Say your activity name is 'Main'

```
    ....
Public class Main extends AppCompatActivity{

Coordinate coor; 

//in the onNavigationComplete method do this

Coordinate coordinate = //..complete this;
coor = coordinate; 
…
…}
```

Comment: I declare ArrayList<Coordinate> res = new ArrayList<>(); outside and inside res.add(coordinate) to add every value into the array list. However, the res.size() is always 0. I can't access the coordinate eventually.

Comment: Note that when you declare ArrayList<Coordinate> red